# How to Cancel a Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

In case of [`BackgroundWorker`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_BackgroundWorker), a cancel can be reported by the `e.Cancel` - property of the `DoWork` - event handler.

How can I achieve the same thing with a [`Thread`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/default.aspx#_Introduction) object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a full example of one way of doing it.

```
private static bool _runThread;
private static object _runThreadLock = new object();

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _runThread = true;
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting thread...");
        bool _localRunThread = true;
        while (_localRunThread)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Working...");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            lock (_runThreadLock)
            {
                _localRunThread = _runThread;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Exiting thread...");
    });
    t.Start();

    // wait for any key press, and then exit the app
    Console.ReadKey();

    // tell the thread to stop
    lock (_runThreadLock)
    {
        _runThread = false;
    }

    // wait for the thread to finish
    t.Join();

    Console.WriteLine("All done.");    
}
```

In short; the thread checks a bool flag, and keeps runing as long as the flag is `true`. I prefer this approach over calling `Thread.Abort` becuase it seems a bit nicer and cleaner.

Comment: Nice, although it's better if you can code it in terms of `WaitHandle` rather than polling. Of course this depends on how the code inside the thread works.

Comment: @Tim: yes, a WaitHandle would probably be a cleaner approach rather than relying on a shared field as in my example. That would remove the need for locking as well, making the code a bit more to the point.

Answer (score 7):

Generally you do it by the thread's execute being a delegate to a method on an object, with that object exposing a `Cancel` property, and the long-running operation periodically chercking that property for tru to determine whether to exit.

for example

```
public class MyLongTunningTask
{
   public MyLongRunninTask() {}
   public volatile bool Cancel {get; set; }

   public void ExecuteLongRunningTask()
   {
     while(!this.Cancel)
     {
         // Do something long running.
        // you may still like to check Cancel periodically and exit gracefully if its true
     }
   }
}
```

Then elsewhere:

```
var longRunning = new MyLongTunningTask();
Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(longRunning.ExecuteLongRunningTask));

myThread.Start();

// somewhere else
longRunning.Cancel = true;
```

Comment: You need to put volatile on the Cancel member to indicate that it will be changed from another thread.

Comment: Well spotted. Should have added that.

Answer (score -1):

A blocked thread can be stopped prematurely in one of two ways:

- Thread.Interrupt
- Thread.Abort

The main question is if the thread works on any ressources which need to be released correctly - in this case - you need to work with a property on the actual object which runs the thread.

Comment: Releasing resources need not be a problem, if the thread uses 'try ... finally' and/or 'using'

Comment: Everybody is arguing against Interrupt and Abort, so don't use them. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort.aspx

Answer (score -1):

There's `Thread.Abort`, which works by injecting a `ThreadAbortException` into the thread. It's a little risky because:

1. Your thread can get stuck if it's executing native code at the time
2. The code in the thread better be exception-safe, because this `ThreadAbortException` could happen on any line of code within it, even something innocent like `i = i + 1`

You're better off coding your own signalling mechanism between your GUI thread and the background thread. It's hard to recommend something without knowing what's going on inside that thread, but where I have a thread that works by waiting on some object in a loop, I use an `AutoResetEvent` and wait on that too.

Comment: I'm reluctant to call some part of the .NET framework (like the `Thread.Abort` method) wrong outright; I just keep a mental list of techniques to avoid.