# Stopping a started thread method loop C#

Tags: c#

Sorry not that experienced in multi-threading. Normally I can google effectively to find my answer but I'm stuck on this one.

I know I could probably use a backgroundworker here, but for the sake of learning I would like to know how and if this can be done manually?

Just trying to start a thread on button push that runs a method loop to print text to the gui, but cannot figure out how to stop this thread running. From what I can pick up, Thread.Abort is not a good way to do it?

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Threading;

    namespace ThreadStopping
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public bool isRunning;
            private static Thread neh;

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                StartThread();
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                StopThread();
            }

            private void StartThread()
            {

                neh = new Thread(Running);
                neh.Start();
                isRunning = true;
            }

            private void StopThread()
            {

                    isRunning = false;

            }

            private void runningText(int value)
            {
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                    Invoke(new runningTextDelegate(runningText),value);
                else
                label1.Text = value.ToString();
            }

            delegate void runningTextDelegate(int value);

            void Running()
            {
                while (isRunning)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                    {
                        runningText(i);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure where to start with this, however a good clue to where you are going wrong would be what happens if you click button1 twice, IsRunning and keepRunning, two different animals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865574/how-to-cancel-a-thread

Comment: Tony: Added bool options in the Start & Stop to stop it running twice. The thread.abort does what I'm after here, so I suppose I'll just carry on until I encounter a problem with it.

Comment: @wannacode can you clarify what your problem is? Maybe I misunderstood what you are after. The Abort answers on the linked question are bad advice which is why I just downvoted them. Dangerous thoughts.

Comment: Yes, I've picked up it being bad practice, but it did do exactly what it was supposed to , and that was stop the thread. You've given me plenty to think & search about, so thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

use background worker instead-of thread

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int p = 0;
        int high = 10000;
        do
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < high; i++)
            {
                if (i%10 == 0 && backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                    break;

                if (i%100 == 0) // for performance purposes
                {
                    p = (int) ((float) i/high*100);

                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(p, i);
                }
            }
        } while (!backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending);          

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.UserState!=null)
        label1.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    }
```

Comment: He does not want to use BeckgroundWorker. He wants to learn how to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You are not synchronizing access to `isRunning`. This is a data race. Your reader thread might never pick up the write (on an instruction level it might be in a register).

Use a volatile variable, or `Thread.VolatileRead/Write`.

You can also just lock access to that variable. If you don't access it too often, you shouldn't worry about overhead too much. Fist concern is correctness (which you have struggled with).

Apart from that your code should be working.

`Thread.Abort` is indeed evil because code must be written to be safe under abortion at an arbitrary instruction. That's rarely the case and you cannot control what code is running if you call to BCL functions.

Comment: Thanks. Small can of worms opened here. I understand what you're saying, but trying to work out how is another issue. Volatile is new to me, only heard of that today but have skipped over locks.

Comment: If you use threads, you suddenly need to understand concurrency issues. Normally, you'd use higher-level primitives. In your case, a `Task` together with a `CancellationToken` would perfectly solve your problem. But if you want to do it the low-level way, you must synchronize properly. Any follow-up questions?

Comment: I'm not really sure why I wanted to understand it the low level way. I first started on threads by learning the Async await, but talked myself into that I was moving way ahead of myself and that I needed to learn standard threading first. I know the background worker is there for me to use for this kind of thing but feel that doesn't teach me anything and is an easy way out. I've also looked at tasks but this has proved to be the most difficult for some reason.

Comment: Even with the new stuff you can never not know the basics and be safe at the same time. Once multiple threads run at the same time, no matter through what framework, you must understand what shared state they work on. In that sense it is good that you make yourself familiar with the issues.