# How to stop Azure Cognitive Service Synthesizer programmatically?

Tags: azure, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I'm working on a C# TTS project, the library I use is Azure `Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Synthesizer`
I can see there is a method `StartSpeakingTextAsync` to start a conversation, but I cannot find any method to stop or cancel a conversation. It is necessary if a conversation is long, after the user given input but the conversation still keeps going. So I have to cancel or stop it programmatically, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal TTS processing for a conversation will be stop after its task completed by `StartSpeakingTextAsync`.

If you need to cancel or stop it manually while in processing, you can create a thread to start its task and then cancel or stop it via [`Thread.Abort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort?view=netframework-4.8) method. I think it's the simplest way to realize your needs.

As reference, you can refer to some SO threads about cancel thread like [How to Cancel a Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865574/how-to-cancel-a-thread).

Comment: The platform I use is dotnet core, I tried thread.Abort() but got an error message:"System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Thread abort is not supported on this platform.'
"

Comment: @JeremyParker Please follow the offical document [`Cancellation in Managed Threads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) to try to use `CancellationToken` to realize it.