# C# Simulate the effect of throwing an exception without throwing an exception

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, antlr4, callstack

I have a specific process I am running... there can be many errors during it as it uses player input, and the errors can be found in various classes because it's big. For clarification, I am building a parser(using antlr4), and many syntax and language errors can happen anywhere in the code because of that(Not actual exceptions, just them writing bad code in my language). I'd like it so that when such an "error" is detected, The entire parsing process would stop but without throwing an exception...

Ik that I can wrap a Try-Catch around the whole process easily and then just use that... but considering how big that is and knowing that it's not recommended to put a Try-Catch on really big stuff unless really necessary, I wonder if there's another way to force the entire callstack to back off.

So far, I have a static property `IsRunning` on a Diagnostic class, and whenever you use the `Diagnostics.PrintError()` method `IsRunning` is set to `false`. But for things to actually stop I need to throw ing `if (!Diagnostics.IsRunning) return null;` practically after every invoke to a method that might call `Diagnostics.PrintError()`... and not only is it quite dumb and hard to maintain... it's extremely easy to miss a check like that and never find out where it comes from...

Does anyone have a better solution or will I be forced to use C# Exceptions and a HUGE Try-Catch around the whole process?

as a reminder, what I want is to be able to completely force-stop the entire parsing process if a certain condition is met(in my case, `!Diagnostics.IsRunning`), but still, continue everything else, essentially popping the entire callstack up to the point that the `Parse()` method was called, and continue normally from there.

Comment: You say you have a process but haven't shown any code, so it's not 100% clear what you're trying to kill and from where, but you can call `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()` from within the process, or `Environment.Exit` to stop the program.

Comment: As I tried to explain... I do not wanna STOP the entire thing, I am running something that does multiple things, among those. it also calls a ```Parse()``` method, this initially sets ```IsRunning``` to ```true```. whenever ```Diagnostics.PrintError()``` is called ```IsRunning``` is set to ```false```, when that happens, I want the PARSING to stop where it is, and for everything else after the original ```Parse()``` method to continue happen as normal. Imagine if I'd throw errors instead of using ```Diagnostics.PrintError()``` and then surround ```Parse()``` with a Try-Catch, same concept

Comment: Is parsing happening in a separate thread? If so, does the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865574/how-to-cancel-a-thread) solve your problem?

Comment: The obvious answer is to put a try/catch block around the `Parse()` call, which is one line of code (i.e. not "huge"). Can you help me understand the issue with this?

Comment: No, it does not happen in a separate thread. I solution to this problem would be to surround ```Parse()``` in Try-Catch, as I said... because when an exception is thrown it'll pop the callstack all the way back to the latest Try-Catch, if there's any. I'd like to pop the callstack all the way back there without a Try-Catch, because I heard using Try-Catch on big chunks of code is a bad habbit

Comment: You also might consider using an event model, and have the parse method in a class that listens for a "StopParsing" event? [Event tutorial](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-event)

Comment: @RufusL ok, assuming I create an event and listen to it... how'd it actually stop without any checks... the ```Parse()``` method calls more methods that call more methods and quickly enough you got a big big tree going on, assuming that setting ```IsRunning``` to ```false``` triggers some event, where would it be listened to and how'd it make the whole thing stop without writing it like a million times which is essentially what I am already doing but with a boolean?

Comment: `try{ Parse(); } catch (Exception e) { logger.Log(e); }` doesn't seem too bad either.

Comment: @RufusL indeed, I am trying to achieve a similar effect without a Try-Catch, as I've heard that the bigger the chunk of code it is surrounding the more it weighs on the performance... and well.. there's a LOT of code

Comment: OP, I respectfully suggest that you may have heard incorrectly. It is very common for there to be catch blocks at a high level. Do you have a reference or a link to the place where you saw or heard this advice?

Comment: @JohnWu I could try to look for it, but overall this is something I've read long ago about only surrounding Try-Catch with the very least of what it needs to contain, as the more it contains the more it damages performance,  but I do not have a link written down for it sadly. If that is the case however, than I suppose a Try-Catch truly is the solution for me... I hope

Comment: Your reasoning is just weak. As a Java thing, ANTLR was designed in that exception oriented way and "using Try-Catch on big chunks of code is a bad habbit" comes from the middle of nowhere. I heard things similar when C/C++ guys talked about Java two decades ago, but honestly speaking the real world examples of Java and C# rendered them just noise.

Comment: `try/catch` will not cause any perf issue for you here. It is slightly more overhead than addressing issues you anticipate might occur before an exception is raised, which you should be doing anyway, but the number of lines of code in a `try` block will not affect performance. I think you may have heard that it's better practice not to use `try/catch` when you can avoid anticipated exceptions in the first place, and if you do use it, it's generally better to catch specific exceptions if possible.

Comment: Possibly.. Regardless, it seems like my best option, thank you